# How to find out size of used libraries in Ember-cli project?

Tags: ember.js

Suddenly the application became too big and I started to wonder how to find out what libraries have the biggest size?

Comment: Agree, this would be useful.  I have a project that is massive now and I would like to know what is causing the blowout.

Comment: Would be good if ember-cli reported this after each build, you might be able to get them to add this feature.

Comment: Ummm, look at the size of the files in your `bower_components` or `node_modules` directories?

Comment: Are you talking about the size on disk of the app?

Comment: No, in the vendor js file created by `ember build -prod`